# How to uninstall Neo4j from Window7?

Tags: neo4j, windows-7-x64, uninstallation

I have been trying to uninstall Neo4j from my laptop.But not able to do so.[This is the snippet of the issue I face every time I try to uninstall.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF3CW.png)

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the **process is running in the background**.
I believe terminating the running neo4j community edition process will allow you to uninstall it.

You should be able to do this from the **Task manager**.

If you dont know how to terminate a running process from the command prompt, you could also try the following

- Bring up the run prompt *(press both the windows key and "r" key)*
- Paste this in

> taskkill /f /im neo4j-ce.exe

(the running task should be terminated)

- uninstall the application now.

Hope this helps.